# use existing C++ code in C# application

Tags: c#, c++, interop

I have some existing C++ classes (including methods and #define constants, as well as a couple of extra C-style functions) that I would like to use in a new C# application.  What's the best way to do this?  I'd rather have everything linked into the one exe, so no DLLs if possible, but just linking into class libraries.

What's the best way to do this?
Is it fairly straight forward, or am I better off porting my original code to C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, your best bet may be to convert your code to C++/CLI, if you want to put them into your project/solution.

If you want to just call those C++ code as an external library, you can use P/Invoke. But my experience with it has been painful. Other than fairly trivial stuff, it has a steep learning curve. But there are really knowledgeable people regarding that subject on SO (like Hans Passant) that can help you.

Of course, you always have the option to rewrite everything in C#.

Comment: I'm in the process of creating a C++ Class library under the CLR, because I assumed this was a good first step.  The modules I'm working with were never organised as a .lib, so it seems logical to take this step and build this with the CLR.Will this be enough to get it all playing happily with C#?

Comment: @user1961169: Since you are starting to create I feel `Managed C++` should be the best option. As, You can mix native and managed code within a single .dll, which is called a mixed-mode assembly.  This is done by compiling some of the C++ files using /clr and some using normal C++

Comment: @user1961169, I'm sorry I can't help you much with that. I barely have any experience with C++, and no experience with C++/CLI. I can't do more than just looking for a link on Google and point you to it, which is something you can do. And one more note, if you decide to use your C++ code as an external library, you should check out http://www.swig.org/ (SWIG). It simplifies the process a lot AFAIK. I haven't used it personally but I have had a friend who used it with great success.

Comment: Couldn't manage to call C functions directly, but I managed to call some of the C-style functions by building a C++ wrapper class to encapsulate them in the class library, and another wrapper class in C# program to massage the data types, as my functions use char * and byte * parameters, which C# really doesn't like.

Comment: I have never had any problem using things like char* and byte* parameters. Where exactly are you having problems with? For example if your char* is a string, it can directly be passed to your C++ code as strings are blittable types.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [PInvoke/DLLIMPORT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx) to call any function in your `C, C++`.

**Update 1**:

> I had a success in calling C function, but not C++ class/methods.

You would have to use Managed C++ to do this. 
[This](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/SamTomato/managed-cpp-wrapper-for-unmanaged-code/) article should help..

**Update 2**: Rearranging as suggested by `David`.

For ***purely C style implementation*** you could use `P/Invoke`.
Reference you could use [LibGit2Sharp](https://github.com/jacobaloysious/libgit2sharp) project. Which consume a native `C.exe` in `C#`.
Here are the `DllImport` Calls [Native Methods](https://github.com/jacobaloysious/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/Core/NativeMethods.cs)

*Note:* Here, you would have to ship the `exe`, it cannot be compiled into any other .Net assemblies.

Comment: is pinovke applicable to C++ class instances? say CPPClass a=new CPPClass; a.SomeMethod();? How to use dllimport for non-C style calls?

Comment: You might have to use `__declspec(dllexport)` on the c++ method.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: your link seems off topic, I am asking on C# side, how to use dllimport or pInvoke to create an instance of unmanaged object instance, and then call its method?

Comment: @David: It was to show how to create a reusable C++ library. Which can then be consumed using C#. In other words, only if you create a C++ function with `_declspec` only then C# can access it using P/Invoke..

Comment: I had a success in calling C function, but not C++ class/methods. Your comments still did not clearly answer this. Would you mind offering some links or examples on how to do this on C# SIDE, how to consume an unmanaged instance in C#, preferably in your updated answer? Thanks!

Comment: I downvoted, as I found LibGit2Sharp project has little relevance with this post, it focus on Git (or VCS) related issues!

Comment: @David: Updated my answer. You would have to use Managed C++ to do this.You can mix native and managed code within a single .dll, which is called a mixed-mode assembly.  This is done by compiling some of the C++ files using /clr and some using normal C++

Comment: @David: Via referring to `LibGit2Sharp` i was trying to provide example just in case if the user was using `P/Invoke`. I provides lots of example w.r.t `Marshalling`.. I am sorry if that didnt help..

Comment: as is repeated again and again, all above (including LibGit2Sharp) is for pure C implmentation, I would be happy to upvote, if you can share sth on using C# to consume C++ instances.,LibGit2Sharp is still misleading and easy to distract others. Do you agree?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30668/discussion-between-jacob-aloysious-and-david)

Comment: Thanks for all the details.  I'll try out the _declspec and see if that helps me to call non-object C functions directly.  I actually had the opposite issue - C++ objects are fine, but C functions needed to be wrapped into an object!  :)